# No implicit conversion of Symbol into String when trying to add attributes to flash messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to customize my flash messages by adding the `account_name`/`company_name` and the email address of the account owner to the flash notice.

Here is the controller action this is supposed to work in:

```
  def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @account.save
        format.html { redirect_to @account, flash[:success] = "#{@account.company_name} has been created. A confirmation email has been sent to #{@account.owner.email}"  }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
      end
    end
  end
```

When I submit the form, the account is saved and all relationships are good. However, I get this error:

```
TypeError at /accounts
no implicit conversion of Symbol into String
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are passing flash as a parameter to the redirect_to method, so you should be using this syntax

```
format.html { redirect_to @account, flash: {success: "your message here" }}
```

The syntax you used would work if you initialized flash before the redirect.

Comment: #FACEPALM thanks so much, i should have caught that.. i suppose staring at this line for the last few hours clouded my mind.